# maximize a function which contains factorials

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, factorial

Suppose I have a function 
$$ f(k) = \binom{500}{k} \binom{500}{1100-3k}$$
where $k$ is an integer from $200$ to $366$. How can I find the maximum analytically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try $f(k)\ge f(k-1)$ and $f(k)\ge f(k+1)$.

Comment: Can't believe that actually simplifies to a linear inequation!

Comment: Just a condition for maxima.

Comment: That's awesome, +1!

Comment: Thanks for this but when you try to solve $f(k) \geq f(k-1)$ you get an equation with 4th degree. Is there a simpler way of doing it?

Comment: @neticin A cubic. I can't think of a better way. What is the source of this problem?